# Qt pointer to a structure

Tags: windows, pointers, structure, libpcap

I use Qt Creator (5.13), I try to create some application with `libpcap`. When I create some method with (struct ethhdr *eth) in a class, I'll get an error:

Code:

```
void SniffPackets::foo(struct ethhdr *eth){
     sprintf(temp_buf, "%3d.%3d.%3d.%3d",
        (int)eth->h_dest[0],
        (int)eth->h_dest[1],
        (int)eth->h_dest[2],
        (int)eth->h_dest[3]);
}
```

Error:
Member access into incomplete type 'struct ethhdr *eth'.

Btw, I use c++99

Comment: `
INCLUDEPATH += C:/WpdPack/Include
LIBS += -LC:/WpdPack/Lib
LIBS += -lwpcap


`

Comment: And header: #include <pcap.h>

Comment: I realized, I look at example for Linux and this structure is in `<net/ethernet.h>`. But I need the same header in Windows. What file is it?

Comment: *"I use c++99"* - C++99 is not a language. There's C++98 and C99 (among others).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Windows, you should use [tcpdump](https://www.tcpdump.org/), there are a few headers for that.

`ether.h`, `ip.h`, `udp.h`, and `tcp.h`

And more, I tried to use `ethhdr`, but it's wrong, obviously this struct for Linux.

Use that for Windows:

```
/*
* Structure of an Ethernet header.
*/
struct  ether_header {
    uint8_t     ether_dhost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    uint8_t     ether_shost[ETHER_ADDR_LEN];
    uint16_t    ether_length_type;
};
```